# How do you asynchronously resolve host names to IP addresses?

Tags: windows, asynchronous, network-programming, dns, overlapped-io

How do you asynchronously resolve host names to IP addresses, preferably with overlapped I/O? GetAddrInfoEx does not support overlapped I/O in Windows 7 and earlier.

I am using native C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the record, this can be done natively on Windows 7, like this:**

- [DnsWriteQuestionToBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682034.aspx) to compose DNS queries yourself for sending.
- [DnsExtractRecordsFromMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682008.aspx) to parse DNS responses yourself after receiving.
- [WSASendTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741693.aspx) in conjunction with [WSARecvFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741686.aspx) in a [IOCP server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx) for async sending and receiving of DNS queries.

*The side effect of this technique is that it's by no means a feat for a novice to easily pull.*

Answer (score 2):

[`libunbound`](http://www.unbound.net/) has an [asynchronous resolver](http://www.unbound.net/documentation/libunbound-tutorial-4.html) in it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather not use a whole external library for a small function.

Comment: @Joshua if you believe that DNS resolution is a "small" function then you are seriously mistaken.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a novice programmer, I kind of assumed it's simple because I thought it's a simple lookup call to a DNS server. Nevertheless, it'd be awesome if I could keep this native, as I also want to learn more about Windows networking.